# How to allow only pdf when uploading file in nodejs without using .extension?

Tags: node.js

I need to restrict DOC,DOCX,JPEG,JPG and other formats and allow only pdf files in nodejs without using . Extension

For example a file name called demo.jpeg and I edit as demo.pdf and I am trying to upload means now my code will allows but I want to restrict that file

what I can do?

Comment: We are talking express here? Any specific form data parser? It's common to rely on [file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) (often called magic numbers) to detect what file you are dealing with without blindly trusting the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use magic numbers for it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/magic-number